# How to determine firebase authentication user state on wake up?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have an app that some elements are dynamic based on if a users was signed in or not. Something like

```
<ion-row *ngIf="firebase.auth.currentUser !== null">
 show stuff when user is logged in
</ion-row>
<ion-row *ngIf="firebase.auth.currentUser === null">
 show stuff when user is not logged in
</ion-row>
```

It works fine on the first time that user transition from not signed in to signed in. But this doesn't work when a user is already signed in and refresh the page. I think it takes time for firebase to initialize `currentUser` and the state changes after the app is initialized.

My question is how can I delay the app initialization after the `currentUser` is properly initialized? Ideally I'd like to subscribe to the event of finishing initialization of `currentUser` but I don't have such signal. Of course I can delay my app initialize for some time and hoping for `currentUser` being populated during that period, but that's really a bad solution I think. What's the elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase web API provides [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#on-auth-state-changed), which adds an observer for changes to the user's sign-in state.

This enables you to postpone showing elements of the page until after the user has been loaded. For example, upon app load, you could display a spinner. Once `onAuthStateChanged` returned, you would close the spinner and update the page.

```
ngOnInit() {
  openSpinner();

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    closeSpinner();

    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
    }
  });
}
```